# How to start Tomcat service properly?

Tags: java, tomcat

Tomcat (checked on 9 and 8.5) do not start after installation (in JRE path folder of my java12 installation is provided).

I've checked stackoverflow before posting this.

1. Using Tomcat9.exe generate "Apache Commons Daemon Service Runner has stopped working" error with "Cancel" option.
2. Using Tomcat9w.exe start config window in which there is written "Service Status: Stopped". Clicking "Start" button shows bar that disappear when loaded to the half and no message shows up.
3. Using Services provided by Windows I can find tomcat service but any attempt to run it give me "Windows could not start the Apache Tomcat 9.0 Tomcat9 service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."
4. Using command line to run catalina.bat or startup.bat does not start service (checked in Services provided by Windows and in Tomcat9w) but in this case trying "http://localhost8080" actually works fine showing tomcat page (those are the only cases it's working).
5. I've checked every path and home stuff and also checked what's in registry editor - every thing looks fine. Log files (catalina and commons-daemon log files do not provide any errors, only information that things starting or running etc. Also I found no error sign in other log files)
6. Configuration looks fine.

I hope to run Tomcat as it should work. Thanks.

Comment: If the default tomcat home page loads and the startup scripts are failing, it sounds like you already have an instance of tomcat running.

Comment: Tomcat page with information "If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!" shows up only when i run bat files in cmd. Any other/standard way to run tomcat just fail and any page never shows up. Also as i said earlier there is only one record of Tomcat service in Services and it's always stopped.

Comment: Are the service and the bat files in cmd launched with the same windows user, and does they share the same environment variables (JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME, PATH, etc...) ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63625

You can either wait for the next round of Tomcat releases that will ship with Commons Daemon 1.2.1 or

- download Commons Daemon 1.2.1 from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/download_daemon.cgi - you'll want commons-daemon-1.2.1-bin.zip
- extract prunsrv.exe and prunmgr.exe and rename them to tomcat9.exe and tomcat9w.exe  and replace the 1.2.0 versions in your Tomcat install